# getElementById isn't working with pageslide.js

Tags: javascript, slider

I use pageslide.js and I have this html code
 EDIT:

```
    <body>
<a href="#modal" class="second">Click me!</a>
<div id="modal">
            <div id="search">
            <img class="icon-search" src="imgs/search.png" onClick= "parse_search();" style="cursor:pointer;">
            <input id="query" name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search..." />
        </div>  
</div>


        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.pageslide.min.js"></script>
         <script >
             function parse_search(){

alert(document.getElementById("query").value)}
        /* Slide to the left, and make it model (you'll have to call $.pageslide.close() to close) */
        jQuery(".second").pageslide({ direction: "right", modal: true });


         </script>

    </body>
```

Then the alert window doesn't give me the value of the input field. It gives nothing for value like that ""

Where is the problem?

Comment: where is your script in the page? is there more code?

Comment: I have edited the original post.Any idea now?

Comment: any console error? btw, check this and add what on it so others can test also: http://jsfiddle.net/bymK3/

Comment: no console error.It popup the alert window but not with the value in the input field. It has nothing for value.like i entered the input text nothing ""

Comment: Is any part of the page loading async/dinamically? What happens if the alert is just: `alert('ping!');`, does it alert?

Comment: No nothing.The hole page is that code i have given above. If i change it to `alert ('ping!');`it alert the ping!

Comment: I believe you, but makes not much sense. Do you have a live link?

Comment: And... I need to ask. Did you write something in the input before you click on image?

Comment: Yes i write something. I dont have a link but the only thing missing is the ` <script src="js/jquery.pageslide.min.js"></script>` so i put it here to copy  http://jsfiddle.net/494n5/

Comment: works for me... http://jsfiddle.net/g2JVK/

Comment: It works but if you add the css it doesnt. Look at this http://jsfiddle.net/g2JVK/1/ The input text is inside the slider. The script i gave you doesnt work in jsfiddle. I dont know why

Comment: if i put the input text outside the slider it works.Inside the slider it doesnt work

Comment: http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/ This is what i am doing.

Comment: Anyway i tried to achieve it with a different way.I have putted the input text outside the slider and i hide-show it with jQuery every time user press the slider to close-open. Thanks man for your time

Comment: I know now what is the problem :/ ... 1 minute and I post back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example why inline script makes troubles.

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('img.icon-search').click(function(){
    var inputValue = jQuery(this).parent().find('input').val();
    alert(inputValue);
});
```

and remove the inline script from your img element. Use just:

```
<img class="icon-search" src="imgs/search.png" style="cursor:pointer;">
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GRHaW/)